# Restar dos Arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript

Que tal la idea seria la resta de dos fechas en `javascript` para luego agregarlo dentro de la función. Les muestro lo que estoy haciendo y así pueden brindarme ayuda.

```
var newYear = new Array(12, 5, 2018);


var jhon = {
    name: "Jhon",
    lastName: "Smith",
    job: "Teacher",
    yearOfBirth: new Array(11, 11, 1996),
    calculateAge: function(){

        this.age = this.newYear - this.yearOfBirth;


    }


};

jhon.calculateAge();
console.log(jhon);
```

Como dije anteriormente, la idea es poder calcular la resta de fechas y luego poder insertarla dentro de las propiedades del objeto.

Comment: no estoy seguro que esta sintáxis sea la correcta var newYear = new Array[12,5,2018];

Comment: si no estoy equivocado se pueden armar matrices de esta manera tambien

Comment: no se usan corchetes si no parentesis

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();

var WakandaKing = {
  name: 'TChalla',
  birthDate: '2000-01-01',
  calcAge: function(){
    return ((date - new Date(this.birthDate)) / 86400000)/365
  },
  country: 'Wakanda'
};

console.log( Math.round(WakandaKing.calcAge() ) );
```

Si quieres calcular una fecha, crea objetos de fechas, no es función de los arreglos hacer esa operación, te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes implementar.

Que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Te doy una opción usando la librería [Moments.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js), que te facilita el manejo de fechas.

```js
var newYear = moment("2018-05-12");

var jhon = {
  name: "Jhon",
  lastName: "Smith",
  job: "Teacher",
  yearOfBirth: moment("1996-11-11"),
  age: null,
  calculateAge: function(){
    this.age = newYear.diff(this.yearOfBirth, "year");
  }
};

jhon.calculateAge();
console.log(jhon.age);
console.log(jhon.yearOfBirth);//vas a otar que la fecha tiene un formato "extraño"
console.log(jhon.yearOfBirth.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));//de esta manera puedas formatear la fecha.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```